# Not able to user WebDriverWait class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am new to Java with Selenium and I am not being able to use `WebDriverWait` class.

I have added dependencies for selenium and webdriver manager and also imported the class on the java class but still I am getting: `WebDriverWait is undefined`.

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ubO.png)

I tried to import the class manually and also tried to change dependencies on the pom.xml file / also updated the project after every change but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

From Selenium 4 and onwards, you should create an object of `WebDriverWait` as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Imports:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Reference: [Class WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)